# unit testing structuremap provides an implementation

Tags: c#, unit-testing

how can I write a unit test to test that asking for an interface does provide an implementation?  I'm using NUnit together with StructureMap

Maybe something like this based on examples in the code?  The problem I have is that I don't know how to setup the test.

**Code snippet**

```
[Test]
public void TestCustomerRegistration()
{
    var res = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ICustomer>();

    Assert.IsNotNull(res, "Cannot get an Customer");
}
```

**This is already present in the code**

Not sure if I have to use a similar thing for my ICustomer test?  Not sure what this is.

```
[TestFixtureSetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>           
    {
        x.AddRegistry<InfrastructureRegistry>();
        x.AddRegistry<RepositoryRegistry>();
    });

    var container = ObjectFactory.Container;
    IDependencyResolver resolver = new SmDependencyResolver(container);
    ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
    {
        x.For<IDependencyResolver>().Use(resolver);
    });
}
```

**Take the folloing MVC controller**

I need to write a test that StructureMap provides 'Customer' when the _customer.GetById(id) is called.  Hope this helps

```
private ICustomer _customer;

public MyController(ICustomer customer)
{
    _customer = customer;
}

public ActionResult GetCustomer(int id)
{
   var result = _customer.GetById(id);  // I need to test that _customer works
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Just curious - why are you testing StructureMap? What is SUT (system under test) in your test fixture?

Comment: I've been asked to test the IoC registration for ICustomer.  The argument was that 'we' wouldn't know that the registration was successful until runtime when something calls it.

Comment: And what benefit of this testing? Real configuration can be easily changed when you will deploy your application. How you can be sure that exactly same StructureMap configuration will be used for unit tests and running application? I believe they do not write unit tests for connection string name checking in config file? :)

Comment: I'm only telling you what the tech lead requested.  I think it's rubbish because the integration tests would flair up any missing registrations but what can I do..  They won't 'pass' my work until it's tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing useless tests for checking some configuration of StructureMap (which is used for unit-tests, not for real running application), then it's easy to do! Use `Assert.IsInstanceOf<T>` to check exact type of returned object. It should be type which you are expecting StructureMap configured to return for customer interface:

```
[Test]
public void TestCustomerRegistration()
{
    var customer = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ICustomer>();
    Assert.IsNotNull(customer, "Cannot get an Customer");
    Assert.IsInstanceOf<SpecificCustomerType>(customer, "Wrong customer type"); 
}
```

*UPDATE* you should test controller in isolation from other objects (otherwise you will not know source of failures) and your controller test should look like (Moq sample)

```
[Test]
public void ShouldReturnExistingCustomer()
{
    // Arrange
    int id = 42; // or random numer
    var dto = // data which ICustomer should return
    Mock<ICustomer> customerMock = new Mock<ICustomer>();
    customerMock.Setup(c => c.GetById(id)).Returns(dto)
    var controller = new MyController(customer.Object);
    // Act
    var result = controller.GetCustomer(id);
    // Assert
    customerMock.VerifyAll();
    Assert.IsNotNull(result); // etc
}
```

This is a controller test and it verifies that controller works (and calls customer to get data). If you want to verify `_customer` works, then you should write customer tests.

Comment: i've updated the question with what seems to be used in existing class files for testing against ioc

Comment: @JamesRadford looks like I'm not getting what you are trying to check. I thought you wanted to verify what implementation StructureMap returns

Comment: I need to test that if a controller requests my new interface that it gets an implementation.

Comment: @JamesRadford if it will not get implementation, your controller test will fail. Also you can get instance as described above, if you really need to check that separately